# talking about possible plans by using modal verbs 'may' and 'might'

Tags: modal-verbs

Here are three example sentence,

> I'm going to Ireland in July.

> I may/might be going to Ireland in July.

> I may/might go to Ireland in July.

In my opinion, the first sentence means I've decided to go to Ireland in July (for sure), while the second sentence means it's possible for me to go to Ireland in July, and I may change my mind.

I am confused about whether the second and the third sentence have the same meaning. I think the last two sentences both represent the possibility of going to Ireland in July. Is there any difference in meaning between them?

Comment: I find only a very slight difference: _I may/might go_ implies that it is my own choice or decision, while _I may/might be going_ suggests that others are involved in the decision, or even that it is outside my control (though in that case I'd be more likely to say _I may have to go_)

Comment: @Colin Fine identifies my intuition as well. I would have posted as much, but I worried that my feelings were idiosyncratic.